# Getting a JavaScript DOM Event for End of Display

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Here's the deal: I have a JavaScript app that builds a table dynamically (DOM building). While it's doing that, a tab is showing a spinning throbber. When I complete page construction, I turn off the throbber.

The throbber is displayed by displaying, then hiding, an img element using CSS (Changing the className property of the img object).

The problem is that the throbber stops a second or so before the constructed DOM object displays.

I can't seem to find an event that reliably fires when the page has completed drawing from a dynamic JavaScript action; only when it is initially loaded (onload() event).

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an event that reliably fires upon successful *display* of an element; whether originally sent in, or whether dynamically created.

Here is the routine that I use to populate the dataset:

```
/************************************************************************************//**
*   \brief Populates the meeting result table for the given data.
****************************************************************************************/
this.domBuilder_PopulateWeekday = function (    in_search_results_json,     ///< A JSON object with the meeting search results.
                                                in_index,                   ///< The 0-based weekday index.
                                                in_sort_key,                ///< The sort key, for the data sort.
                                                in_sort_dir,                ///< The sort direction, for the data sort. It will be 'asc' or 'desc'.
                                                in_tabObject                ///< The tab object, which will be set to selected when the weekday is done.
                                            )
{
    if ( null != this.my_body_container )   // Clear any preexisting condition.
        {
        this.my_body_container.parentNode.removeChild ( this.my_body_container );
        this.my_body_container.innerHTML = '';
        this.my_body_container = null;
        };

    this.my_body_container = document.createElement ( 'div' );        // Create the main table element.
    this.my_body_container.className = 'bmlt_table_div';
    this.my_body_container_header = null;
    this.my_body_container_body = null;

    this.my_container_object.appendChild ( this.my_body_container );        
    this.my_body_container.appendChild ( this.domBuilder_PopulateWeekdayHeader ( in_index, in_sort_key, in_sort_dir ) );
    this.my_body_container.appendChild ( this.domBuilder_PopulateWeekdayBody ( in_search_results_json ) );

    in_tabObject.className = in_tabObject.rest_className + ' is_selected';
};
```

This can be seen in action on [this page](http://bmlt.magshare.net/what-is-the-bmlt/sample-bmlt-searches/the-bmlt_table-shortcode/standard-default-bmlt_table-demo/), which loads a big dataset, and takes awhile to draw.

Click on one of the unselected tabs to see what happens. The throbber stops, the weekday reappears, then, a second or so later, the data appears beneath it. What I want, is for the throbber to continue until after the data has been drawn.

Comment: Where's the *throbber*? The classes that the throbber uses? Any events added already?

Comment: My connection must be too fast, I don't see any animation except for that logo of a spinning globe. I searched the code couldn't find *throbber*. All I can do is blindly advise you to use `setTimeout`, how to do it, I couldn't say because I do not know the what and the where.

Comment: The throbber is in the weekday tabs. It's a standard spinning wheel.

Comment: It is fast. That's the problem.

Comment: When you click on a weekday -that has not previously loaded-, the selected tab stays dark, and a spinning throbber replaces the weekday abbreviation. The page content below disappears, then the throbber stops, is replaced by the weekday abbreviation -very quickly- and the dataset draws after a brief delay.

Comment: A good way to get the throbber to display is to click on one of the table header cells (re-sorts). The throbber stays up for the appropriate amount of time...which makes me go "hmmm..."

Comment: "-that has not previously loaded-" It's too fast and the cached assets are making it faster. Count yourself fortunate that being too fast is the worst of your problems. :P

Comment: Yeah. The issue is the drawing time. In most cases, the dataset will be so negligible that it won't matter. This is a rather extreme sample.

Comment: I tried what you advised in a quick succession of clicks and yet there was no delay. All I can think of is to strategically place a `setTimeout` within a callback from the event that triggered the throbber. That way the callback can execute a couple of seconds latter than it usually does. I take it that you just want to test the throbber, because not seeing a throbber/loader is a good thing.

Comment: No, the problem is that there's a period of time where there is no throbber (I can make it work here), and there should be.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. It was a logic bug in another routine. My bad.

Comment: The problem was that I undid the throbber in a mouseout() handler. D'oh!